# How to get popup window with multiple file uploads in asp.net vb

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Hi I want to display popup window with multiple `fileupload`

when I click `UploadDocument button` I have tried this but I dint get the correct one it displays next to `Upload Document button` but I want to get when I click `UploadDocument button` please help me to do this.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form1">
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Document" />
<label>
    upload file
    <input type="file" multiple="true" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</label>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can use `jquery modal popup` functionality inside that you can merge your `file uploads`

Comment: I don't want to merge file uploads I want to get fileuploads buttons when I click uploaddocument as a popup window

Comment: you need `multiple fileupload`, can you specify how much you need ??

Comment: in 1st row>>>Choose file (textbox) Browse Button
in 2nd row>>>Destination folder (textbox) Choose Folder
confirmation buttons>>>>Ok Cancel
the above box should popup when I click Upload Document button

Comment: try with the below given solution, may be that can help you

Comment: will try and let u know thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I have created a demo using `Modal Popup`

Have a look below

```js
 $(function () {
            modalPosition();
            $(window).resize(function () {
                modalPosition();
            });
            $('.openModal').click(function (e) {
                $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeIn('fast');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $('.close-modal').click(function (e) {
                $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
        function modalPosition() {
            var width = $('.modal').width();
            var pageWidth = $(window).width();
            var x = (pageWidth / 2) - (width / 2);
            $('.modal').css({ left: x + "px" });
        }
```

```css
.modal-backdrop
        {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: none;
        }
        .modal
        {
            width: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            z-index: 1020;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border-radius: 6px;
            display: none;
        }
        .modal-header
        {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #FFF;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        }
        .modal-header h3
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
            line-height: 40px;
        }
        .modal-header h3 .close-modal
        {
            float: right;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        .modal-footer
        {
            background-color: #F1F1F1;
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: right;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top: solid 1px #CCC;
        }
        .modal-body
        {
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        }
```

```html
<asp:Button ID="btn_open" runat="server" Text="Open Modal" CssClass="openModal" />
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>
               File Upload <a class="close-modal" href="#">&times;</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Button ID="btn_close" runat="server" Text="Upload Document" CssClass="modalOK close-modal" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop">
    </div>
```

Dont forget to add the `Jquery Plugin`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Hope that helps you

Have a look at the below screenshot

[image: Multiple files Upload]

Comment: hi what you sent is correct but it should display as popup window

Comment: on clicking of button, it is opening the `popup window` only. Did you added the basic plugin of `jquery` ?? `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: In between of jquery only I added code what you have sent

Comment: the HTML parts needs to be added after `form` tag and jquery to be added on the Top of javascript code

Comment: if you don't mind can you send me the screen shot what is the result if you run the above code even when I run in the fiddle got the same result

Comment: yes I did the same thing and .modalpopup where to add?

Comment: actually it will not run in the jsfiddle as it is aspx control, I will give you the screen shot of my code

Comment: I cant see anything its two small

Comment: its just simple html, css and js has to be added.  What especially are you not able to see ?

Comment: I have added the code here https://jsfiddle.net/a7ajgr2n/ u just simply need to copy paste and test it accordingly. I am going for lunch now will be back in 20 mins. Do let me know if it does not works for you

Comment: the screen shot what you sent is very small If I enlarge its very blur cant see anything

Comment: i dont know what did you tried, can you copy paste your code and give the link

Comment: can you come on chat here for discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99104/importand-discussion

Comment: ohh sorry I don't have 20 reputations to chat there

Comment: refresh your page and try now..!

Comment: please access my request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99105/discussion-between-coder-and-avi).

Comment: click the above link and come on chat